# Captcha Control Validation On ClientSide using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to draw a Captcha ,And a textbox where user is going to put the value of captcha and before submitting to server the textbox value has to be validated, that is Client side validation.and if the tebox value doesnot match with the captcha value then it will show error message before redirecting to server.In ASP.NET

Comment: you can random create captcha and also store the crate captcha text in a hidden value and match that on form submit using javascript.

Comment: do you want captcha as image or text?